# What is the theory/algorithm behind extract_patches function of scikit-learn?

Tags: python, image-processing, multidimensional-array, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm using `extract_patches_2d` and `extract_patches` for local patch extraction from a 2d image and I'd like to have the theory and references that explain the implemented method for patch extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what theory you refer to, under the hood these methods are just clever array manipulation (spoiler: *numpy* array manipulation).

- The first one, [`extract_patches_2d`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html), is a simple 2-D wrapper over `extract_patches`, which calls

  ```
  extract_patches(image,
                  patch_shape=(p_h, p_w, n_colors),
                  extraction_step=1)
  ```

  and reshapes the result ([source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py#L299)).
- The second one, `extract_patches`, is a wrapper as well, this time over [`numpy.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). It only prepares `2*n` shape and striding to delegate the job to

  ```
  as_strided(arr, shape=shape, strides=strides)
  ```

  Here's its [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py#L241).
- What's really interesting is [`numpy.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). From it's documentation:

  > `as_strided` creates a view into the array given the exact strides and
  >   shape. This means it manipulates the internal data structure of
  >   ndarray and, if done incorrectly, the array elements can point to
  >   invalid memory and can corrupt results or crash your program. It is
  >   advisable to always use the original `x.strides` when calculating new
  >   strides to avoid reliance on a contiguous memory layout.

  So, basically, the result is the wrapper over same array in memory (a *view*), which provides index lookup and each index is looking into a particular region inside `x`. [`numpy.ndarray.view`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) is the core numpy function which allows to view inside an existing array without memory reallocation. If you wish to dive deep into how numpy performs array manipulation and views, [numpy internals](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/internals.html) is a good place to start.